# Jquery Post + run php file > hide the form > give message

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, forms, post

here is my code about jquery post. I can't make it work somehow. I spent hours :( what I miss here?! when I run the code, It loads same page :(

> I want it to run the php code under
>   query.php and hide the contact form
>   and give "thanks!" message at send
>   submit button click. (with no page
>   loading)

appreciate helps!

---

**PHP Form**

```
<form id="commentForm" name="contact" method="post" action="">
    <ul id="contact-form">
        <li><label>Full Name: *</label><input type="text" name="full_name" class="txt_input required" /></li>
        <li><input type="submit" value="Send" id="btnsend" name="btnsend" class="btn_submit" /></li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

---

**SCRIPT**

```
$(function() {

    $("#btnsend").click(function() {
        var dataString = 'fullname='+ escape(full_name);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "query.php?act=contact",
            data: dataString,
            success: function() {
            $('#contact-form').hide();
        $('#contact-form').html("<p>thanks!</p>")
        .fadeIn(1500, function() {$('#contact-form').append("");});
       } 

    });

    return false;
    });
 });
```

Comment: That <label> element is rather useless. There is no for attribute and no input inside it.

Comment: @David: the Label element is not supposed to contain the input, nor does it need a for attribute.

Comment: See http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.9.1 — if you have a for attribute, the label is associated with the element that has an id that matches the for attribute. Otherwise, the label is associated with its contents. In this case, the label isn't associated with any form control, which makes it useless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem lies in: `var dataString = 'fullname='+ escape(full_name);`

Try: `var dataString = 'fullname='+ escape(document.contact.full_name.value);`

Eg:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
 <title>Example</title>

 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
   $("#btnsend").click(function() {
    var dataString = 'fullname='+ escape(document.contact.full_name.value);

    $.ajax( {
     type: "POST",
     url: "query.php?act=contact",
     data: dataString,
     success: function() {
      $('#contact-form').hide();
      $('#contact-form').html("<p>thanks!</p>").fadeIn(1500, function() { 
       $('#contact-form').append("");
      });
       }  
    });

    return false;
   });
  });
 </script>
</head>

<body>
 <form id="commentForm" name="contact" method="post" action="">
  <ul id="contact-form">
   <li><label>Full Name: *</label><input type="text" name="full_name" class="txt_input required" /></li>
   <li><input type="submit" value="Send" id="btnsend" name="btnsend" class="btn_submit" /></li>
  </ul>
 </form>
</body>
```

Make sure `query.php` exists though else it won't execute the call back function at success.

Also make sure you click the button and not press the `ENTER` key as that will submit the form normally (you have only defined an event handler for click not keypress)

Comment: oooohh! I can't believe! thanks so much.... my main was about query.php access :/ now it gives thanks message, with fading effect : )

Now I'm going to work on the email action and form control!
thanks!

Comment: how can I run it with an another validation script? :/ I use the script at the link http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/custom-messages-metadata-demo.html .

Probably I need to call this post script from the success case of validation script? or no way?

Comment: If you're going to use jQuery, then use jQuery to get the value of the input as well.  Also, you'd have to run the validator before doing the ajax post. The simplest way is to change to handle the submit event on the form and make sure the validator's handlers are applied before your ajax submit handler.  That way your function will only be called if the form is valid.

Comment: Although I load jquery-post.js after the validation, it takes post action first. can it be because of I run post code on submit button click?
 
<!-- Form Validation -->   
<script src="inc/validation/lib/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="inc/validation/jquery.validate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 
 <script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $("#commentForm").validate();
 });
 </script>  
 
<!-- Jquery Post -->
<script src="js/post-contact.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Answer (score 2):

You can [preventDefault](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/jQuery.Event#event.preventDefault.28.29) on the button click or return false on the form's submit event:

```
$(function() {
    $("#btnsend").click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var full_name = $('input["name=full_name"]').val();
            var dataString = 'fullname='+ full_name;
            $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: "query.php?act=contact",
              data: dataString,
              success: function() {
                    $('#contact-form').hide();
                    $('#contact-form').html("<p>thanks!</p>")
                                      .fadeIn(1500, function() {$('#contact-form').append("");});
               }
        });
    });
});
```

or:

```
$('#commentForm').submit(function() {
    return false;
});
```

Comment: @artmania - also, you can safely remove the form's action attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$(function() {

$("#btnsend").click(function() {

        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "query.php?act=contact",
          data: { fullname: $('input[name=full_name]').val() },
          success: function() {
        $('#contact-form').hide();
                $('#contact-form').html("<p>thanks!</p>")
        .fadeIn(1500, function() {$('#contact-form').append("");});
           } 

    });

    return false;
});
});
```

Comment: +1 - I think he'll also run into a problem because "btnSend" is a submit button.

Comment: @Paul Suart: Ahh yes, possibly. He is returning 'false' though, which may cancel the event.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have at least 3 problems here.  First, you are referencing full_name as if it were a variable.  I believe this is causing a javascript error which aborts the function and allows the default action (post) to proceed.  Second, you probably need to encode ALL of the form parameters, including `act`.  This is may be causing an invalid URL to be sent and thus the action appears not to have been invoked -- you can check this by looking at the request that is sent with Firefox/Firebug.  Third, you are attempting to replace the contents of a list with a paragraph element.  This is invalid HTML.  I'd replace the entire list with the paragraph (and I don't get what appending an empty string does at the end so I've omitted it).

Note I've changed this to work on the submit event of the form -- so it won't matter how it's submitted.  Also allows me a little jQuery niceness in not having to look up the form again.

```
 $('#commentform').submit(function() {
   var $this = $(this);
   $.ajax({
     url: "query.php",
     data:  { 'act': 'contact', 'full_name', $('input[name="full_name"]').val() },
     success: function() {
        $('#contact-form').remove();
        $this.hide().html("<p>thanks!</p>").fadeIn(1500);
     }  
  });
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my way to call PHP function directly via jQuery

```
// in html file
<script language="javascript">
  $.post("thisisphp.php",{ func:"true", varbl: 'valu2' },function(data) {
    $('.thisdiv #subdiv').html(data);
  });    
</script>
```

PHP file thisisphp.php

```
<?php
    // include connection creating file.
    require_once("database.php");
    $db = & new Database();

    function getDateAppointments($varible1, $varible2, $db) {    
      $q_appointment = "SELECT * FROM `tbl_apoint` WHERE ap_date = '".$varible1."'"; 
      $s_appointment = $db->SelectQuery($q_appointment);

      while($r_appointment = mysql_fetch_array($s_appointment))
      {
        echo '<div id="appoinment">'.$r_appointment['ap_title'].'</div>'; 
      }     
    }    

    /* This function for set positions of the day */        
    switch($_POST['func']) {
      case 'true':
        getFunc1($_POST['varbl'], 'S0001', $db);
        break;
      default:
        getFunc2($_POST['varbl'], 'S0001', $db);        
    }    
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9111618/925058) help you?

PS: you can put your hidding and showing form script inside onSucces and onError functions.